# Underflow occurred in compilation

Tags: compile

This code shown below works well for n<=10, if n>11, Mathematica gives the message

> CompiledFunction::cfne: Numerical error encountered; proceeding with
>   uncompiled evaluation. >>.

So compilation failed, my questions is: How can I make it compilable?

```
cf = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
   With[{c = Table[j + i*I, {i, -1.2, 1.2, .006015}, {j, -1.8, 0.6, .006015}]},
        Exp[-Abs@Nest[#^2 + c &, c, n]]]];
```

Comment: Well to be fair, those numbers are in underflow territory... a "straightforward" way (but terribly slow) would be to use exact arithmetic (but you can't use `Compile`).

Comment: I don't think compiling failed. The message means that the function, which works in machine precision, detected an underflow condition and decided to continue with the more accurate symbolic version.

Comment: You can set a value as the infinity and for everything greater you set the `Exp` to zero. I assume that you are studying something about Julia sets so the divergence area is not the one that you are mainly interested at.

Comment: How about RuntimeOptions -> "Speed" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main error is that the numbers get too large in the `Nest` call, greater than is possible to represent as machine reals/complexes, and you get overflow.  Here I just cap them at a large number 10^10, but small enough that `Exp` won't underflow.

```
cf = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
   With[{c = Table[j + i*I, {i, -1.2, 1.2, .006015}, {j, -1.8, 0.6, .006015}]}, 
    Exp[-Abs @ Nest[Map[If[Norm[#] > 1.`*^10, 1.`*^10, #] &, #^2 + c, {2}] &, c, n]]],
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

Same idea, but somewhat faster:

```
cf = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
   With[{c = Table[j + i*I, {i, -1.2, 1.2, .006015}, {j, -1.8, 0.6, .006015}]},
     Exp[-Abs @
       Nest[With[{u = UnitStep[1.`*^10 - Abs[#]]}, u # + (1 - u) 1.`*^10] &[#^2 + c] &,
        c, n]]], 
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we stop the iteration before the values get small enough to cause the underflow errors.

```
cf = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
       Table[Exp[-Abs@NestWhile[#^2 + j + i*I &, j + i*I, Abs[#] < 10. &, 1, n]], 
       {i, -1.2, 1.2, .006015}, {j, -1.8, 0.6, .006015}]];
```

Instead of `Nest` it uses `NestWhile` and the condition is `Abs[#] < 10. &` so it iterates up to `n` times, but stops iterating if the argument gets larger than 10, which means `Exp[-Abs[10]]` is getting small. You might want to change this value. The other change was to not use `With` and the `c` variable; the reason for this change (using `Table` instead) is that the test didn't like having a whole matrix of values passed to it.